# Linux Platform Drivers: How to pass DMA Ops to cells?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, dma

I am writing a multi function driver (mfd) for a PCIe device with DMA capabilities. Several cells are added through `mfd_add_devices`.

I found that the `struct device*` of the top level mfd driver has the correct `struct dma_ops` set to allocate buffers, manage DMA transfers etc. Howewer, the child platform drivers get another `struct dma_ops` filled with dummy implementations.

How can arrange for the child platform drivers to get/inherit the correct set of DMA operations from their parent?

Comment: Thru other means obviously. For example, IOMMU implementation can provide such. Or you need to create your own quirk driver (see, for example, swiotlb).

Comment: The parent driver already has the correct DMA ops set (fit for SMMU). I can access `child->dev->parent` to get the correct ops, but it seems like a hack as it depends on how i nest my drivers.

Comment: DMA operations should be provided to the device which *actually does* DMA. See, for example, _drivers/mfd/intel-lpss*.c_ how the IOMMU ops are being distributed to the devices.

Comment: I checked `intel-lpss.c`, `intel-lpss-acpi.c` and `intel-lpss-pci.c` and I cannot find, how the IOMMU ops are being distributed to the devices.

I see that the driver optionally adds some kind of of DMA cell, however I see no link being made from the other cells to that DMA device.

Can you point me to the place in source where the distribution of IOMMU ops happens?

Comment: perhaps this sheds a light https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/dma/idma64.c?id=5ba846b1ee0792f5a596b9b0b86d6e8cdebfab06

Comment: Answering to your Q in the comments: it depends on the architecture. For x86 (Intel) it may be either global options: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iommu/intel-iommu.c#L5052 or in case of untrusted devices: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iommu/intel-iommu.c#L5669

Comment: If I'm reading the patch to `idma64.c` correctly, the child device just goes one level up for dma operations, i.e. it uses `pdev->dev.parent` instead of `&pdev->dev` for DMA operations, but continues to use `&pdev->dev` for all other operations. This is to say that the child driver knows that it has a parent driver with correctly set dma_ops. It also means that the dma_ops are not passed down, but grabbed from below. Correct?

Comment: DMA operations (for PCI device) are applied by corresponding architectural code. Above I showed you how IOMMU on x86 does that. Otherwise it's done in corresponding architectural code (like *arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.c*).